# List TCP connections

Tags: text-processing, io-redirection, netstat

How can I format netstat output so I have a list of TCP connections made to the server?

A bit like this:

```
192.168.234.1 51780
192.168.234.221 51444
192.168.234.251 51447
```

The closest I got was six columns with all the values from the netstat, but I just need the origin IP of the established connections using
`netstat -na -t | grep ESTABELECIDO`

Comment: To what server?  Incoming connections?

Comment: is `netstat -p tcp -n | awk '$NF ~ "ESTABELECIDO"{print $5}'` sort of what you are looking for?

Comment: I updated the post, sorry for that @jesse_b

Answer (score 2):

For the formatted output , you can use [awk](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) and [tr](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/tr1.html)

```
netstat -na -t | awk '/ESTABELECIDO/{print $4}' | tr ':' ' '
```

As, you asked origin IP and origin IP will be from our machine only, so I mentioned field `$4` in awk, otherwise use `$5` in `awk` for other machine IP address.

Comment: @Jesse_b Yes you are right, i have edited my answer to reflect your suggestion